# jQuery addClass to <li> when <a> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to the li when the a.more is clicked. But it isn't working.

```
        <ul>
            <li id="post-4" class="post">
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="date">12/12/2013</span>
                    <h3>The Title</h3>
                    <div class="post-excerpt">
                    <p>The excerpt will show</p>
                        <a class="more" href="#">read more..</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                    <p>The full content</p>
                    <a class="less" href="#">close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
   jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.more', function(){
       jQuery(this).addClass('active');
   });
   jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.less', function() {
       jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: where is `a.less`???

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. See edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add parents(). to addclass on li

```
jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.more', function(){
   jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
});
jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.less', function() {
  jQuery(this).parents('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

Try above code.

Comment: if you found help full . pls up vote and accept answer.

Comment: keep in mind that this solution will add the `active` class to all parent `li` elements. If you have nested `li`/`ul` it will be applied to all ancestor `li` elements. I believe `.closest()` is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to add and remove `class` of `li`

```
jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.more', function(){
    jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
});
jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.less', function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the user can only see one of the two links at any moment, you could use a single function

```
jQuery('.post').on('click', 'a.more, a.less', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
});
```